# How to check/trap if the decimal number ends in 0

Tags: php

I have a value that has 2 decimal places. Now I'm trying to catch the ones that end in 0 (example: 123.50).

I was able to catch the ones that end in `.00` and that end in different numbers such as `.23` / `.88`, etc.

Here's my code:

```
if(fmod($totalAmountToPay, 1) !== 0.00){ 
    //traps ending in .23 / .88
}
else {
    //traps ending in .00
}
```

But this time I need to trap the ones that end in `.50` / `.30` / `.60`.

Comment: ok. And the problem is...? What have you tried? What went wrong?

Comment: Multiply by ten: `fmod(10.0 * $totalAmountToPay, 1)`.

Comment: `!== 0.00` - strict comparison like that with float values, is probably not a good idea to begin with.

Comment: We generally don't do your homework for you. You can check [php.net/manual](https://php.net/manual) and look for functions which might help you work on a solution.

Comment: Why do you divide by 1 ?

Answer (score 1):

> use explode function and convert to array from the decimal point.

```
$number = "125.50";
$valArr = explode('.',$number);
echo substr( $valArr[1],1,1); // 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `sprintf()` to format to one decimal (i.e. tenths), then compare that with the original number. If they are the same, it means the original number only had tenths (i.e. ends with `.?0`), otherwise it had hundredths (or smaller).

```
if ( $n == sprintf("%0.1f", $n ) ) {
    // Ends with .?0
} else {
    // Does not end with .?0
}
```